# It's possible to create a hook to send an email in pyinstaller execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, hook, pyinstaller

I want to send an email to me always when `pyinstaller` is executed.

It's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use smtplib library in your python code to send the email. Like described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

However, since it needs network connectivity, you can not always guarantee the network available on the user machine when pyinstaller based application is running.

You can check the network connectivity and fail the execution of your program (with an appropriate user message)if the network is not available.

Comment: Sure, feel free to mark as answered if you find it useful